# Match keywords (patterns) from file against multiple files

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

Sorry for the obscure title, here is my problem and what I want to do.

My files:

```
\\mydir\keywords.txt
\\mydir\textfile1.txt
\\mydir\textfile2.txt
\\mydir\textfile3.txt
etc
```

I have "keywords.txt" with a lot of keywords (strings) that I want to match against the "textfile1.txt" and so on and receive an answer of which  filename that contains a match.

```
$keywords = Get-Content -Path '\\mydir\keywords.txt' | Out-String
Select-String -Path '\\mydir\*.txt' -Pattern $keywords
```

I.e. search recursively through all files that are .txt in \mydir\ and use the file "keywords.txt"'s content as keywords to search for.

`Get-Content` by default returns the values as an array, `Out-String` should convert those into a string.

Would appreciate all help!

Comment: You want them as an array I think, as `-Pattern` accepts array input. Drop the `Out-String` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `| Out-String` part from your code and it will work as you intend I believe. This is because `Get-Content` will create an array of string in `$Keywords` and the `-Pattern` parameter accepts string array input:

You should also use `-SimpleMatch` unless you want your Keywords to be interpreted as RegEx patterns.

```
Select-String -Path '\\mydir\*.txt' -Pattern (Get-Content -Path '\\mydir\keywords.txt') -SimpleMatch
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, both your answer and @MarkWragg gives me what I want, I had actually overlooked that since both answers also dumps the entire array since it finds matches using "keywords.txt" and also searches in all txt-files (*.txt).

I removed the keywords.txt and put it another folder and it worked :D

So my actual code was:
`$content = Get-Content '\\mydir1\keywords.txt'
 Select-String -Path '\\mydir2\*.txt' -pattern $content`